# SQL Query is taking infinite time when using with order by

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

Below is my SQL Query

```
select top(10) ClientCode
FROM (((Branch INNER JOIN BusinessLocation ON 
Branch.BranchCode=BusinessLocation.BranchCode) 
INNER JOIN Center ON BusinessLocation.LocationCode = Center.LocationCode) 
INNER JOIN Groups ON Center.CenterCode = Groups.CenterCode) 
INNER JOIN Client ON Groups.GroupCode = Client.GroupCode 
WHERE
((Client.CBStatus) IS NULL) AND ((Branch.PartnerName) in 
('SVCL','Edelweiss'))
order by Client.ClientCode DESC
```

When i run it without order by it runs fine , but with order by it is not finishing execution. Why is this behavior ?

Comment: How big are your tables? Do you have an index on Client.ClientCode?

Comment: Total 1324738 records , no index on Client.ClientCode

Comment: Add indices on the join columns.

Comment: Please note : it was running file till yesterday and i have another query with same join and order by just column selection is different which is still working fine and this one not

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , how can set indexes on join ?

Comment: You can start here: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/indexes.php

Comment: Actually indexing will be a problem here , We insert data into this table very frequently through web application so it is not advisable to create index on this table.

Comment: Not advisable to create index? If you don't have several thousands of inserts per minute, you'll be just fine...

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič , I tried with index like this , but still not finishing execution CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [clientcode_idx] ON [dbo].[Client]
(
 [ClientCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,right, lacking of indices on table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select using TOP statement, calculations and joins for every row are not necessarily calculated. When you try to order, at least one cell for all rows need to be calculated. It is a long query because your table is large and the behavior is not faulty. Don't let the fast running query without the order by mislead you about the complexity of your second query.

You can create an index on clientcode column. That would speed things up.

Comment: tried with this , but still ewwwwwww  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [clientcode_idx] ON [dbo].[Client]
(
 [ClientCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO